# PowerShell, Extension Methods, and Monkey Patching

Tags: .net, powershell, extension-methods, monkeypatching

Is it possible to write extension method in PowerShell? or to bolt a new method on top of an existing type like [string] live at runtime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know of a way to patch a type with an extension method.  But it's certainly possible to patch an object via the add-member cmdlet

```
PS> $a = "foo"
PS> $a = add-member -in $a -memberType ScriptMethod -name Bar -value { $this + "bar" } -passthru
PS> $a.Foo()
foobar
```

**EDIT** Explain the completely and totally readable PowerShell Syntax :)

I love PowerShell but it really does come up with cryptic syntax from time to time.

- "-in": This is short for inputObject and essentially says add member to this
- "-memberType": There are many different types of values you can add to a runtime object including methods, note properties, code method, etc ...  See "get-help add-member -full" for a complete list
- "-passthru": Take the object that just had a member added to it and push it down the pipeline.  Without this flag the assignment would be assigning and empty pipeline to `$a`.
- The assignment call is basically ensuring that `$a` now has the method you added

Comment: +1 Could you elaborate on the syntax a little. The $a = add-member looks a little strange and what does the -in and -passthru switches do?

Comment: Add-Member also works with the pipeline 
PS> $a = "foo"
PS> $a | add-member -memberType ScriptMethod -name Bar -value { $this + "bar" } 
PS> $a.Foo()
foobar

Comment: @JaredPar: A few questions: "$a = Add-Member" seems to make "$a = $null". Shouldn't the member type be "ScriptProperty" and the call "$a.Bar()"? I must be mising something, but I only got this working by changing all that (PS V1).

Comment: Well, Tyndall wanted a method, not a property.

Comment: Very true. I was missing the "-passthru" switch... However, I still don't get what's the point of calling Foo() when then new method was named Bar()... :-?

Answer (score 11):

If you have a method or property you want to add to a particular type, you can create a custom type extension via PowerShell's adaptive type system.

A custom type extension is a an XML file that describes the property or script method to a type and then load it into the PowerShell session via the Update-TypeData cmdlet.

A great example of this can be found on the [PowerShell Team Blog - Hate Add-Member? (PowerShell's Adaptive Type System to the Rescue)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/hate-add-member-powershells-adaptive-type-system-to-the-rescue/)

Comment: Yes, THIS is the answer the original poster is looking for.

Comment: I did stumble upon this method. Not sure. I'd like to keep as much as I can in PowerShell versus XML. hmmm. I guess I would use this method if I had lots and lots of "mods" to do.