# "Add-Member" to a type instead of only an object of that type in PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell

In PowerShell you can extend objects :

> The **Add-Member** cmdlet lets you add members (properties and methods) to
>   an instance of a Windows PowerShell object. For example, you can add a
>   NoteProperty member that contains a description of the object or a
>   ScriptMethod member that runs a script to change the object.

However :

> The properties and methods that you add are added only to the
>   particular instance of the object that you specify. **Add-Member** does
>   not change the object type. To create a new object type, use the
>   Add-Type cmdlet...

**Example :**

```
$s = "Hello World" |    Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty Reverse {$this[$this.Length..0] -join ""}

$s Hello World

$s.Reverse dlroW olleH
```

Is there a simple direct manner to do the same thing for all instances of that type, just like what [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) do in C#, something that would do something somehow similar to the following :

```
$s = "Hello World" |    Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty Reverse {$this[$this.Length..0] -join ""}

$s Hello World

$s.Reverse dlroW olleH

$a = "Aymen"
$a.Reverse nemyA
```

Comment: Interesting reading: http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/09/06/extension-methods-in-windows-powershell.aspx

Comment: Also check out the unaccepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840907/powershell-extension-methods-and-monkey-patching

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a *simple* way to do it, but it can be done by modifying the type data for the target type. This requires the `Get-TypeData`/`Update-TypeData` cmdlets. It cannot be done with `Add-Member`. Below is an example of adding a property to DateTime, `UtcSeconds` which is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 in the UTC time zone. You can add other members as well, like methods, alias or note properties.

```
$td = Get-TypeData System.DateTime
$scriptBlock = { ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeToUtc($this) - (new-object System.DateTime 1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,"Utc")).TotalSeconds }
$scriptProperty = new-object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.ScriptPropertyData "UtcSeconds", $scriptBlock
$td.Members.Add("UtcSeconds", $scriptProperty)
Update-TypeData $td -Force
```

Note that if you writing a module, existing types can be extended more conveniently via a [types.ps1xml file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847881.aspx).